# Nginx double directory reference during static files deployment

Tags: nginx, web-deployment

I am deploying my static files with Nginx and Gunicorn. Below is my Nginx config file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xx.xx;
    root /home/briansia/django_blog;

    access_log /home/briansia/django_blog/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/briansia/django_blog/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/briansia/django_blog/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/briansia/django_blog/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Nginx could not serve my static or media files, instead I got:

```
2021/11/14 09:09:08 [error] 303783#303783: *3 open() "/home/briansia/django_blog/static/static/blog/main.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)

2021/11/14 09:09:08 [error] 303783#303783: *4 open() "/home/briansia/django_blog/media/media/profile_pics/yasharn_r5D4eQk.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I noticed that the directory **static** and **media** are referenced twice. I then tried all sort of trailing slash combinations for the static and media location inside my config file.

Comment: Check the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directives. Either `root /home/briansia/django_blog` (preferred) or `alias /home/briansia/django_blog/...` should be used. Moreover, using `root /home/briansia/django_blog` globally you already have all the required conditions for serving your static files and can shorten you corresponding location blocks to `location /static/ {}` and `location /media/ {}` (or even `location ^/(?:static|media)/ {}`.

Comment: Made the changes to my config file and now it works! Thanks a lot Ivan.